# Options: Edit and Design disappeared

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I updated my SQL Management Studio to the latest version yesterday and then I was going to alter my database and I encountered a strange change on the program. When performing the right click on the table the options: Edit top 200 rows and Design were not there! Please, can anyone help me with this?

My SQL version:

[image: My SQL version:]

The problem:

[image: The problem:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [reported issue with the July 2016 SSMS update](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/2883440).  It appears to affect only SQLEXPRESS and LocalDb.

Consider reverting to the June 2016 SSMS update if you can't live without the menu options until it is fixed.

Comment: I'll rollback to June 2016 version then. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: @RicardoFerreira, if you only use Express/LocalDb for development, you might consider moving to the free Developer Edition.  Developer has the same features as Enterprise but is licensed only for development and testing.